# How to assign one array elements to another array?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter-3

I have two tables in database one table is **saloon_staff** and the second table is **saloon_staff_timings**

**Saloon_staff**
[image]

**saloon_staff_timings**
[image]

Now in the **saloon_staff_timings** table, I am inserting the timing of saloon staff. I have run two queries to get data from the table, The first query is getting the names of saloon staff through saloon_staff_id in saloon_staff_timings table and the second query is getting the timings of the saloon staff.

Here is my code.

```
<?php 

 foreach ($saloon_staff as $key => $value)
  {
    echo"<tr>";

    echo"<td> $value->staff_name </td>";


      foreach ($staff_timings as $key => $stf_timngs) 
       {
  ?>
     <td><?php echo $stf_timngs->start_time ?></td>
  <?php 
        } 
       echo"</tr>";
     } 
?>
```

The result of this code.
[image]

The first foreach loop is showing the names of saloon staff and the second foreach loop is showing the timings of the saloon staff. I have a problem in the second foreach loop, what I want to get is the name and the time against that name. But for now, I am getting all the times available in the database, which is wrong.

Saloon staff timings print_r($saloon_staff)

```
  Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [staff_name] => Salman Iqbal
                [id] => 1
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [staff_name] => Alludin 
                [id] => 2
            )

    )
```

Saloon staff timings print_r($staff_timings)

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 1
                [saloon_staff_id] => 1
                [day] => Monday
                [start_time] => 01:03:00
                [end_time] => 18:00:00
                [break_start] => 00:00:00
                [break_end] => 00:00:00
                [saloon_profiles_id] => 1
                [phone_number] => 098098098
                [email] => SalmanIq@facebook.com
                [appointments_enabled] => 1
                [role_in_saloon] => Owner
                [name] => Salman Iqbal
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 1
                [saloon_staff_id] => 1
                [day] => Tuesday
                [start_time] => 03:06:00
                [end_time] => 19:04:00
                [break_start] => 00:00:00
                [break_end] => 00:00:00
                [saloon_profiles_id] => 1
                [phone_number] => 098098098
                [email] => SalmanIq@facebook.com
                [appointments_enabled] => 1
                [role_in_saloon] => Owner
                [name] => Salman Iqbal
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 1
                [saloon_staff_id] => 1
                [day] => Wednesday
                [start_time] => 02:08:00
                [end_time] => 21:08:00
                [break_start] => 00:00:00
                [break_end] => 00:00:00
                [saloon_profiles_id] => 1
                [phone_number] => 098098098
                [email] => SalmanIq@facebook.com
                [appointments_enabled] => 1
                [role_in_saloon] => Owner
                [name] => Salman Iqbal
            )

        [3] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 1
                [saloon_staff_id] => 1
                [day] => Thursday
                [start_time] => 01:00:00
                [end_time] => 14:08:00
                [break_start] => 00:00:00
                [break_end] => 00:00:00
                [saloon_profiles_id] => 1
                [phone_number] => 098098098
                [email] => SalmanIq@facebook.com
                [appointments_enabled] => 1
                [role_in_saloon] => Owner
                [name] => Salman Iqbal
            )

        [4] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 1
                [saloon_staff_id] => 1
                [day] => Friday
                [start_time] => 01:06:00
                [end_time] => 19:09:00
                [break_start] => 00:00:00
                [break_end] => 00:00:00
                [saloon_profiles_id] => 1
                [phone_number] => 098098098
                [email] => SalmanIq@facebook.com
                [appointments_enabled] => 1
                [role_in_saloon] => Owner
                [name] => Salman Iqbal
            )

        [5] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 1
                [saloon_staff_id] => 1
                [day] => Saturday
                [start_time] => 01:09:00
                [end_time] => 15:09:00
                [break_start] => 00:00:00
                [break_end] => 00:00:00
                [saloon_profiles_id] => 1
                [phone_number] => 098098098
                [email] => SalmanIq@facebook.com
                [appointments_enabled] => 1
                [role_in_saloon] => Owner
                [name] => Salman Iqbal
            )

        [6] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 1
                [saloon_staff_id] => 1
                [day] => Sunday
                [start_time] => 00:03:00
                [end_time] => 19:09:00
                [break_start] => 00:00:00
                [break_end] => 00:00:00
                [saloon_profiles_id] => 1
                [phone_number] => 098098098
                [email] => SalmanIq@facebook.com
                [appointments_enabled] => 1
                [role_in_saloon] => Owner
                [name] => Salman Iqbal
            )

        [7] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 2
                [saloon_staff_id] => 2
                [day] => Monday
                [start_time] => 02:03:00
                [end_time] => 16:09:00
                [break_start] => 00:00:00
                [break_end] => 00:00:00
                [saloon_profiles_id] => 1
                [phone_number] => 98790809809
                [email] => alludin@gmail.com
                [appointments_enabled] => 1
                [role_in_saloon] => No Access
                [name] => Alludin 
            )

        [8] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 2
                [saloon_staff_id] => 2
                [day] => Tuesday
                [start_time] => 01:09:00
                [end_time] => 20:01:00
                [break_start] => 00:00:00
                [break_end] => 00:00:00
                [saloon_profiles_id] => 1
                [phone_number] => 98790809809
                [email] => alludin@gmail.com
                [appointments_enabled] => 1
                [role_in_saloon] => No Access
                [name] => Alludin 
            )

        [9] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 2
                [saloon_staff_id] => 2
                [day] => Wednesday
                [start_time] => 01:09:00
                [end_time] => 21:00:00
                [break_start] => 00:00:00
                [break_end] => 00:00:00
                [saloon_profiles_id] => 1
                [phone_number] => 98790809809
                [email] => alludin@gmail.com
                [appointments_enabled] => 1
                [role_in_saloon] => No Access
                [name] => Alludin 
            )

        [10] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 2
                [saloon_staff_id] => 2
                [day] => Thursday
                [start_time] => 11:00:00
                [end_time] => 13:09:00
                [break_start] => 00:00:00
                [break_end] => 00:00:00
                [saloon_profiles_id] => 1
                [phone_number] => 98790809809
                [email] => alludin@gmail.com
                [appointments_enabled] => 1
                [role_in_saloon] => No Access
                [name] => Alludin 
            )

        [11] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 2
                [saloon_staff_id] => 2
                [day] => Friday
                [start_time] => 01:07:00
                [end_time] => 21:00:00
                [break_start] => 00:00:00
                [break_end] => 00:00:00
                [saloon_profiles_id] => 1
                [phone_number] => 98790809809
                [email] => alludin@gmail.com
                [appointments_enabled] => 1
                [role_in_saloon] => No Access
                [name] => Alludin 
            )

        [12] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 2
                [saloon_staff_id] => 2
                [day] => Saturday
                [start_time] => 00:00:00
                [end_time] => 00:00:00
                [break_start] => 00:00:00
                [break_end] => 00:00:00
                [saloon_profiles_id] => 1
                [phone_number] => 98790809809
                [email] => alludin@gmail.com
                [appointments_enabled] => 1
                [role_in_saloon] => No Access
                [name] => Alludin 
            )

        [13] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 2
                [saloon_staff_id] => 2
                [day] => Sunday
                [start_time] => 00:00:00
                [end_time] => 00:00:00
                [break_start] => 00:00:00
                [break_end] => 00:00:00
                [saloon_profiles_id] => 1
                [phone_number] => 98790809809
                [email] => alludin@gmail.com
                [appointments_enabled] => 1
                [role_in_saloon] => No Access
                [name] => Alludin 
            )

    )
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: well you could just use a join statement no need to use two queries

Comment: Use a JOIN and do it on the Database end.

Comment: If you keep your current method of storing all data in `$saloon_staff`/`$staff_timings`, you would need to have a way to correlate the data, ie, use the `saloon_staff_id` as the key(s) in your `$staff_timings`. Then you could do -> `foreach($staff_timings[$key] => ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple You are missing if statement...Try this:-

```
<?php 

foreach ($saloon_staff as $key => $value){
    echo"<tr>";
    echo"<td> $value->staff_name </td>";
    foreach ($staff_timings as $key => $stf_timngs){
       if($stf_timngs->saloon_staff_id == $value->id ){?>
       <td><?php echo $stf_timngs->start_time ?></td>
   <?php }  }
   echo"</tr>";
 } ?>
```

Hope it helps!.. if you want to do with joins refer the @sajeevan answer

Answer (score 2):

just use INNER JOIN for join both table and display the data appropriate columns by use condition

```
SELECT ss.*,sst.* FROM `Saloon_staff` INNER JOIN `Saloon_Staff_timings` AS sst ON sst.`saloon_staff_id`= ss.`saloon_profile_id`
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi try with the below snippet. It should work.

```
<?php 

  foreach ($saloon_staff as $key => $value) {

  echo"<tr>";
  echo"<td> $value->staff_name </td>";

  foreach ($staff_timings as $key => $stf_timngs) {

     if($value->id  == $stf_timngs->saloon_staff_id ){
          echo  "<td>".$stf_timngs->start_time."</td>";
      }

    } 

   echo"</tr>";

 }
```

In your code, you were just printing out trimmings irrespective of which user timings. so I just added a check against user id in first foreach loop with staff profile id in timings table. which should result in the trimmings related to a particular user.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check ID of `$saloon_staff` `id` and `$staff_timings` id. The reason why it prints all because we are not checking it

**Here is the code:**

```
foreach ($saloon_staff as $key => $value){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $value->staff_name . '</td>';
    foreach ($staff_timings as $key2 => $stf_timngs) {
        // Check ID if equal
        if($value->id == $stf_timings->saloon_staff_id){
            echo '<td>' . $stf_timngs->start_time . '</td>';
        }
    } 
    echo"</tr>";
}
```

I also clean code. This is much easier to read since I included the html tags in echo rather than separating the html.

Comment: wrong it should it be $value->id not $value->saloon_profiles_id